# Using an Oracle to Avoid Computable Functions

Tags: logic, computability, oracles

Is there a non-computable set $X$ and a a partial computable function $F$ such that for all natural numbers $e$, if $\Phi_e^X(0)$ halts, then
$$F(e) > \Phi^X_e(0)?$$

If $X$ computable, then there is such an $F$. For example, $F$ might have the instructions

1. Run $\Phi_e(0)$
2. Add 1 to the result
3. Halt.

However, if $X \geq_T 0'$, then there is no such $F$. To see this, suppose there were. Then, by s-m-n theorem, the following function $G$ would be $0'$-computable.

$$\Phi^X_{G(e)}(x) = \begin{cases}
F(e) + 1 &\text{if } \Phi_e^X(0) \text{ converges}\\
1 &\text{if } \Phi_e^X(0)\text{ diverges}.
\end{cases}
$$

Then, by the recursion theorem, there is $a$ such that $\Phi^X_{G(a)} = \Phi^X_a$. The computation $\Phi^X_a(0)$ cannot diverge as if so, then $\Phi^X_a(0) =\Phi^X_{G(a)}(0) = 1$, a contradiction. Therefore, $F(e) = \Phi_a^X(0) = \Phi_{G(a)}^X(0) < F(e)$, a contradiction.

Comment: One obvious necessary requirement for this is for $X$ to be **computably bounded** (also called **hyperimmune-free**), that is, for every total $X$-computable function $\Phi_c^X$ to be bounded by some total computable function $g$. (To see this, let $f(c,n)$ be a total computable function such that $\Phi_{f(c,n)}^X(0)=\Phi_c^X(n)$ and let $g=\lambda n. F(f(c,n))$.) Interestingly, no nonzero degree below ${\bf 0'}$ is computably bounded, although nonzero computably bounded degrees do exist. I suspect this is also sufficient.